# VS Code: Include file not found in browse.path, but the IDE recognizes the name as I type it

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, include-path

I get `Include file not found in browse.path`.

However the IDE sees the path as I am typing `#include "ntrip_caster.h"`.
It gave the header in a list but than a couple seconds later shows it can't find it once it is in the code.  How to direct VS to where the headers are ???

Also note this is OS Ubuntu on WSL... I don't know if there is problems with paths with WSL Ubuntu.

---

I did the following: none worked...

---

go to File -> Preferences -> Settings in VS Code and change "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default" to "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser".

---

```
//#include "ntrip_caster.h"
//#include "/home/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_caster.h"
//#include "../src/ntrip_caster.h"
//#include "ntrip_caster.h"
//#include "ntrip_caster.h"
//#include "${HOME}/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_caster.h"
#include "ntrip_caster.h"
```

---

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                //"${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/xxx/ntrip/src/"
                //"${workspaceFolder}/nn"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            //"cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            //"cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            //"intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
            
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

---

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                //"-I./include -std=c++11 -pthread lpthread",
                "-std=c++11 -pthread lpthread",
                //"${file}",
                //"/home/xxx/ntrip/src/mount_point.h",
                "/home/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_caster.cc",
                //"/home/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_caster.h",
                "/home/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_util.cc",
                //"/home/xxx/ntrip/src/ntrip_util.h",
                "/home/xxx/ntrip/examples/ntrip_caster.cc",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```